# Cloud Firestore query and limit doesn't query all data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a list with tags that I want to search in and retrieve data that matches the search.

I can retrieve all data correct with this query

```
  searchTags(search: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Tag> {    
    return this.afs.collection(this.dbPathTags, ref => ref.where('tag', "<=", search))
  }
```

But the problem is that i want to limit the results to 5, since I'm planning to show them in a dropdown/autocomplete (like tags in SO)

After adding the limit, the query is just searching for the top 5 items from db and ONLY returns any of them if they matches. Wanted result is query filter ALL items then returns 5 items

```
  searchTags(search: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Tag> {    
    return this.afs.collection(this.dbPathTags, ref => ref.where('tag', "<=", search).limit(5))
  }
```

When searching for "a" I get this result

[image]

But when searching "m" or "math" I don't get anything, note that "math" is also in the db and is displayed when the limit is off

[image]

Limit off

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have considered using startAt with the Limit rather than the where.
Firebase Pagination docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors.

edit: .orderBy('field', 'order') when order is not present ascending order is default

```
searchTags(search: string): AngularFirestoreCollection<Tag> {    
    return this.afs.collection(this.dbPathTags, ref => ref.orderby('field', 'order').startAt(search).limit(5))
  }
```

Maybe something like that?

Comment: Yes that did work! But would be nice to have the order from the where. Ill just have to filter it on my own after then.

Comment: For example you could. So filter visible with a where and then orderBy, and startBy
Add the where in front of the orderBy